# Clickstream Tracking in Veeva CRM

Tags: javascript, salesforce, crm

I am working with Veeva CRM, trying to use Click Stream Tracking. I have the code which I am using and trying to track the Presentation id, Product Key Message, track an Element Description and Answer.

Can anybody help with the code that I am using.
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
   <meta charset="utf-8"> 
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
   <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags --> 
  <title>CLM_CERT_HCPName</title> 

  <!-- Bootstrap --> 
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <script src="js/veeva-library-3.0.js"></script> 
  <script> 
    function start(){ 
     header_getAccountName(); 
    } 
  function header_getAccountName(){    com.veeva.clm.getDataForCurrentObject("Account","Name",header_displayAccountName)} 
 function header_displayAccountName(result){ 
var AccountNameHTML = document.getElementById("hcpName"); 
AccountNameHTML.innerHTML += result.Account.Name;com.veeva.clm.getDataForCurrentObject("Presentation","Survey_vod__c",header_getSurveyID); 
} 

function mySaveObject(){ 
//This is the start of my JSON object 
var myCallClickStream = {Call_vod__c, Key_Message_vod__c}; 

//i am using my JSON obj name with the field API name of the call clickstream     object obj.apiName then set the value. obj.apiName= value;] 
// Create the record using the com.veeva.clm.createRecord 
com.veeva.clm.createRecord("Call_ClickStream_vod_c", myCallClickStream, printSavedResults)}
function printSavedResults(result){ 
alert(JSON.stingify(result)); 
} 
</script> 
</head>
```

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have also some sample code to try out but not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
function mySaveObject(){
var myCallClickStream = {};
myCallClickStream.Text_Entered_vod__c = "i will put some text here";

com.veeva.clm.createRecord("Call_Clickstream_vod__c", myCallClickStream, printSavedResults)
}

function printSavedResults(result) {
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

Comment: @il_raffa i am trying to track the text that has been entered, store the key messages and presentation name for the Veeva Presentation. I have edited the code in the main stream to include a sample code that I have been supplied with.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you still need help on this or not. But my team uses a simple method in every project to simplify the tracking process. The below was modified to fit some of your naming conventions/needs.

```
// clmDescription - string submitted as the description to be tracked
// clmAnswer - string submitted as the answer to be tracked`
// callback - call back function which will be used to return the information

function mySaveObject( clmDescription, clmAnswer, clmCallback ) {
    var url = window.location.pathname,
        filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
        clmTrackingID = filename.replace(".html", "");

    var myCallClickStream = {};

    myCallClickStream.Track_Element_Id_vod__c = clmTrackingID;
    myCallClickStream.Track_Element_Type_vod__c = clmDescription;
    myCallClickStream.Selected_Items_vod__c = clmAnswer;
    myCallClickStream.Track_Element_Description_vod__c = clmAnswer;

    // var myJSONText = JSON.stringify( myCallClickStream );

    com.veeva.clm.createRecord( Call_Clickstream_vod__c, myCallClickStream, clmCallback );
}
```

Simply call the method and pass in your parameters, including your callback method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not work.  I get an error saying "Can't find variable Call_Clickstream_vod__c".  veeva-library.js is included. Is there an extra library required?

Comment: Call_Clickstream_vod__c is an object available to you within Veeva (from Salesforce). The Veeva JS library helps connect to it, but does not include the object reference. In order to write to the object, you need to have selected an account first. Without it, you would be tracking data against nothing - which I believe is not allowed.

Comment: Oddly enough, it was putting Call_Clickstream_vod__c that made it work.  I could not tell you why.

Comment: But now it says the JSON is malformed.  message = createRecord: Request: veeva:saveObjectV2(Call_Clickstream_vod__c),value("{\"Track_Element_Id_vod__c\":\"CLM_SHARED_SLIDE01\",\"Track_Element_Type_vod__c\":\"Engagement\",\"Selected_Items_vod__c\":\"true\",\"Track_Element_Description_vod__c\":\"true\"}"),callback(com_veeva_clm_createRecord) failed: JSON string format is invalid: Expected either '[' or '{'.

Comment: Hey Dave, I just checked the Veeva JS library. Looks like createRecord is looking for an object. I modified the answer above. Simply pass your JSON object and NOT a stringified version.

Comment: Yes, working now...thanks!  I mistyped earlier, my message should have said "it was putting Call_Clickstream_vod_c *in quotes* that made it work."  Now I get a successful result.